# Ruby on Rails Template::Error Heroku logs

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I get this error when I run heroku logs:

```
 ActionView::Template::Error (Missing partial Partial/menu with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder]}. Searched in:* "/app/app/views"

<%= render "Partial/menu"%>
```

_menu.html.erb is in views/partial

Everything works fine on localhost and the partial is there. What is the problem?

Comment: You need to give us your partial that you are trying to render. No one can help you with a one line error.

Comment: is the view in `Partial/` or `partial/`. That may matter.

Comment: also, aren't partials typically `_something` on the filesystem?